# Ubuntu 12.04 LTS -- more compact?

Tags: ubuntu

I am running Ubuntu 12.04 LTS and I'm a beginner so please go easy on me. I am looking for a way to effectively make the icons / spacing / text size smaller (than their default) so I can fit more on a screen. This would effectively be similar to increasing the screen resolution, but it's always at it's maximum. How would you suggest I best do this?

Answer (score 0):

For me it's currently in Settings > desktop > Icons > Icon size.

For what it's worth I'm running Xubuntu (Ubuntu with a different desktop manager) so these words/locations may be approximate for you.

Answer (score 0):

In file manager (nautilus), **Edit** -> **Preferences**, the **Views** tab entry for **Icon View Defaults** affects both the icon view in nautilus itself and the icons on the desktop, though the text alongside option affects only the file manager.